# Why JQuery Form submitHandler does not refresh its callback?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using the [JQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/), the [JQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and the  jqTransform plugin.

I have a hidden form which I make visible to add or edit stuff. Edit or Add actions trigger the next function call.

```
function activateAddForm(formId,callback) {
    $('#'+formId).jqTransform().validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $(form).ajaxSubmit( {
                    dataType: "json", 
                    success: function(json) {
                        callback(json);
                    }
                });                 
            }
        }); 
}
```

Each call with different parameters. For add, I call it with

```
activateAddForm('add-new-form',addToy);
```

for edit, I call it

```
activateAddForm('add-new-form',editToy);
```

This is what happens:

- Reload the page.
- Edit one toy.
- Submit the form.
- The editToy function is called.
- Try to add something.
- The function activateAddForm is called with addToy as callback but once the form is submitted the editToy function is called instead.

If the first thing I do after a reload is add a Toy. Then the addToy function is always called.

I have tried adding:

```
function activateAddForm(formId,callback) {
    $('#'+formId).ajaxFormUnbind();
    ...
}
```

or

```
function activateAddForm(formId,callback) {
    $('#'+formId).resetForm();
    ...
}
```

But it has not work. Any idea what can I do?

### Workaround trials

Activa's suggestion of adding the line:

```
$.removeData($('#'+formId)[0],'validator');

function activateAddForm(formId,callback) {
$('#'+formId).jqTransform();
$.removeData($('#'+formId)[0],'validator');
$('#'+formId).validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit( {
                dataType: "json", 
                success: function(json) {
                    callback(json);
                }
            });                 
        }
    }); 
}
```

Casues the next:

- Reload the page.

  - Edit one toy.
  - Submit the form.
  - The editToy function is called.
  - Try to add something.
  - The form editToy funciton is called, followed by a call to add function.

The above fix does not work but seems to be in the right direction.

Any more ideas?

Comment: Would you mind adding a link to a working demo page, so we can see all of your code, plugins, etc. working together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the source code for the validator plugin, it seems that once you call the validate() function, subsequent calls to validate() have no effect.

A workaround would be to call the following before calling validate():

```
$.removeData($('#'+formId)[0],'validator');
```

EDIT:

Checked your code again, and I think we need to change strategy :-)

```
function updateAddForm(formId,callback) {
$('#' + formId).data("successCallback",callback);
}

function initAddForm(formId) {
$('#'+formId).jqTransform()..validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
                $(form).ajaxSubmit( {
                        dataType: "json", 
                success: function(json) {
                        $('#'+formId).data("successCallback")(json);
                }
                        });                     
        }
    }); 
}
```

At the start, you call:

```
initAddForm('add-new-form');
```

To set the callback, you call:

```
updateAddForm('add-new-form', addToy);
```

or

```
updateAddForm('add-new-form', editToy);
```

That will probably do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your workaround, it does not work but it seems to go in the right direction. Any more ideas?

Comment: Thanks, a lot man. It worked!. I you ever drop to Spain, let me buy you a beer. :-)

Comment: If you're close to Valencia, I may take you up on this :)

Comment: I am close to Madrid. We do not have sea but it is nice too.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is much simpler if you just change the submitHandler of the validator instead of putting it in the parameters of the validate function.

```
$('#form').validate().settings.submitHandler = function () {
   // your function goes here.
}
$('#form').submit();
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks for your solution. I extracted the submitHandler attribute from the validation rules and now it's working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#comment').validate({
      rules:{
               comments:{required:true}
         },
    messages:{
               comments:{required:'Please enter the comment' }
          },
           submitHandler: function(form) { //asynchronusly post the form data

                        var url=MAIN_SITE_URL+'rating/getrate/';
                        var comments=$('#comments').val(); 
                        url+='rating/comment/'+comments;
                        $.post(url,$('#rating').serialize(),
                                             function(response){alert(response); }

           }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to answer your question. If you are working in firefox,
try to install firebug plug-in and try to inspect form element.

From the description here I can see you are probably using two different form elements
with same ID on the same page. The first thing I would do is to distinguish forms by
unique ID element like:
   edit-form
   add-form

just a thought I hope someone will have a better answer for you.

Comment: I have firebug plugin installed and use it all the time